# Parallel Sieve of Eratosthenes using Clojure Reducers

Tags: clojure, parallel-processing, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes, reducers

I have implemented the Sieve of Eratosthenes using Clojure's standard library.

```
(defn primes [below]
  (remove (set (mapcat #(range (* % %) below %)
                       (range 3 (Math/sqrt below) 2)))
          (cons 2 (range 3 below 2))))
```

I think this should be amenable to parallelism as there is no recursion and the reducer versions of remove and mapcat can be dropped in. Here is what I came up with:

```
(defn pprimes [below]
  (r/foldcat
   (r/remove
    (into #{} (r/mapcat #(range (* % %) below %)
                        (into [] (range 3 (Math/sqrt below) 2))))
    (into [] (cons 2 (range 3 below 2))))))
```

I've poured the initial set and the generated multiples into vectors as I understand that LazySeqs can't be folded. Also, r/foldcat is used to finally realize the collection.

My problem is that this is a little slower than the first version.

```
(time (first (primes  1000000))) ;=> approx 26000 seconds
(time (first (pprimes 1000000))) ;=> approx 28500 seconds
```

Is there too much overhead from the coordinating processes or am I using reducers wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to leetwinski this seems to work:

```
(defn pprimes2 [below]
  (r/foldcat
   (r/remove
    (into #{} (r/foldcat (r/map #(range (* % %) below %)
                                (into [] (range 3 (Math/sqrt below) 2)))))
    (into [] (cons 2 (range 3 below 2))))))
```

Apparently I needed to add another fold operation in order to map `#(range (* % %) below %)` in parallel.

```
(time (first (pprimes   1000000))) ;=> approx 28500 seconds
(time (first (pprimes2  1000000))) ;=> approx  7500 seconds
```

Edit: The above code doesn't work. `r/foldcat` isn't concatenating the composite numbers it is just returning a vector of the multiples for each prime number. The final result is a vector of 2 and all the odd numbers. Replacing `r/map` with `r/mapcat` gives the correct answer but it is again slower than the original `primes`.

Answer (score 0):

as far as remember, the `r/mapcat` and `r/remove` are not parallel themselves, thy are just producing foldable collections, which are in turn can be subject to parallelization by `r/fold`. in your case the only parallel operation is `r/foldcat`, which is according to documentation "Equivalent to `(fold cat append! coll)`", meaning that you just potentially do `append!` in parallel, which isn't what you want at all.

To make it parallel you should probably use `r/fold` with `remove` as a reduce function and `concat` as a combine function, but it won't really make your code faster i guess, due to the nature of your algorithm (i mean you will try to remove a big set of items from every chunk of a collection)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I was aware that r/mapcat, r/remove, etc. were just recipes to be executed in the future but I was of the impression that the r/foldcat on the end would run each operation in parallel. You got me thinking that another  fold may be necessary. After all the mapping of `#(range (* % %) below %)` across 2 < odds < below was what I really wanted to happen in parallel.